# N Unit Alphabetical Order Assertion

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a search box on a website that returns search results, based on keyword (storing these as a list in c#)

There are filter options which I need to test, one of which is product name A-Z.

When this is selected, the search results should be sorted accordingly.

Is there anyway to assert that this has been done against the list with N Unit ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to ensure they are sorted, use the [constraint assertion syntax](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=constraintModel&r=2.6.4).  It's as simple as this:

```
string[] yourActualSearchResults = new string[] ( "alpha", "beta", "gamma" );

Assert.That(yourActualSearchResults, Is.Ordered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `CollectionAsserts` which [succeed if the two collections contain the same objects, in the same order](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.4). Of course this requires you to have *expected* collection sorted, like:

```
var expected = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
var actual = ...
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Similar effect can be achieved with *constraint* model and [Enumerable.SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var expected = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
var actual = ...
Assert.That(expected.SequenceEqual(actual), Is.True);
```

But this will have less localized failure message (*true vs false*), rather than pointing where collections differ (which is the case for `CollectionAssert`).